# How can I remove whitespace between static text elements on the same row?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using JasperReports to generate a report that contains, for each field, just one element.

For example, the report might look like this:

```
I, $F{Name}, $F{Surname}, declare that... etc.
```

The issue I'm coming across is the space between the field $F{Name} and ${Surname}. If the first field only contains a few letters, then there will be a noticeable space between the two fields, rendering the document like so:

```
I, Nortius                        Maximus
```

What I would like to achieve is for the empty space between the two fields to be removed whilst still being able to leave plenty of space for each of the fields so that long name won't be expanded vertically. Is there any way of doing this using JasperReport?

Comment: You can use one textField (`textFieldExpression`) for showing all information. Example: `<textFieldExpression><![CDATA["I " + ($F{Name} == null ? "" : $F{Name}) + " believe in"]]></textFieldExpression>`

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed. Putting several fields inside of the CDATA attribute did the trick.